# FB.ui: "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options" on mobile

Tags: facebook, angularjs, share

I am doing a Facebook share.

It works well on desktops but on mobiles phones it throws this error (I can see in the console).

> Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

The Facebook page is opened but it is all blank with a loading button in the center.

```
FB.ui({
  method: "feed",
  name: fb_title,
  link: fb_link,
  picture: fb_pict,
  caption: fb_caption,
  description: fb_desc
}, function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    //
  }
});
```

I don't know if it can be linked, my app is running on AngularJS 1.08.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why, but after many tests, here is my conclusion:

FB.ui "feed" does not work **on mobile** when the description is **more that about 80 characters** AND is written in **Asian characters**.

Works well with a lorem ipsum of 250 characters for example.

Answer (score -1):

Having just experienced a similar problem reported by a family member, I'm adding an answer because I couldn't find any answers that matched my problem.

In my case, I was calling (approximately)

```
FB.ui({'method':'apprequests',
       'data':'',
       'message':'hello'})
```

This resulted in a console error like

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php? 
skip_api_login=1&api_key=[redacted]' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

This was the case for trying to use the app inside Facebook either at its apps.facebook.com URL, or for using it on its own page that uses Facebook login, for that user. However, the same call worked fine in both views on other machines, for other users, running the same browser version. The page doesn't use frames, so this error seemed extra weird.

After some debugging, I asked the user to try a different browser (to disambiguate whether the issue was browser-related / account-related); it worked okay in a different browser for the same user.

Long story short, one possible cause of weird "refused to display in a frame" errors from the Facebook API, when it happens for some users/machines/browsers but not others, is malware that injects a frame into the DOM in the user's browser.